# sql sum() across multiple columns

Tags: sql

I have a table with 7 columns:

```
Color1 (string)
Color2 (string)
Color3 (string)
Use1 (decimal)
Use2 (decimal)
Use3 (decimal)
Date


Col1  |  Col2  |  Col3 |  Use1  |  Use2  |  Use3  |  Date
---------------------------------------------------------------
Red   |  Green |  Red  |  2     |   6    |  8     |  30-01-2018
Red   |  Black |  Black|  5     |   7    |  9     |  25-02-2019
Green |  Red   |  Green|  1     |   3    |  3     |  30-05-2019
```

I need to get all the colours and useage into one list:

```
Color  |  Month  |  Usage  |
----------------------------
Red    |    01   |   10    |
Red    |    02   |    5    |
Red    |    05   |    3    |
Green  |    01   |    6    |
Green  |    05   |    4    |
Black  |    02   |    16   |
```

Struggling on finding a way to do this in SQL....
If someone could help me with this, i'll really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider seperately each `col` versus `use` by `summing up` usage inside and outside of the subquery against the probability of repeating months for colors for the whole data which may be not shared here.

```
select color, month, sum(usage) as usage
  from
  (
   select col1 as color, extract(month from Date) as month, 
         sum(use1) as usage from tab group by col1, extract(month from Date) union all
   select col2, extract(month from Date), 
         sum(use2) from tab group by col2, extract(month from Date) union all
   select col3, extract(month from Date), 
         sum(use3) from tab group by col3, extract(month from Date)
  ) q
 group by color, month;
```

By the way we don't know about the `DBMS`. `Oracle`, `MySQL`, `Postgres` support `extract()` function.

Comment: Apart from the circular reference sum(usage) as usage it worked and solved my problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One method is `union all`.  The exact syntax may vary by database, but the idea is:

```
select color, month, sum(usage)
from ((select col1 as color, month(date) as month, (use1 + use2 + use3) as usage
      from t
      ) union all
      (select col1 as color, month(date) as month, (use1 + use2 + use3) as usage
       from t
      ) union all
      (select col1 as color, month(date) as month, (use1 + use2 + use3) as usage
       from t
      )
     )
group by color, month;
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought this is a fun question to give a try at unpivot of t-sql. Unfortunately, unpivot cannot split the colour and usage into two columns, so i combine the colour and usage into nvarchar instead. Not ideal, unfortunately. But perhaps it gives somebody else some ideas.

```
select date, col 
from (select mth, col1_use1 = colour1+convert(nvarchar, usage1)
           , col2_use2 = colour2+convert(nvarchar, usage2)
           , col3_use3 = colour3+convert(nvarchar, usage3)
        from colourusagemonth)  m
unpivot 
    (col for colour in (col1_use1, col2_use2, col3_use3) 
    ) as unpvt;
```

Comment: Dont assume the sql tag is about SQL Server as the sql is about writing ISO/ANSi SQL standard SQL.. This query does not confirm to that

Comment: I did not assume, it was clear to me he wasn't using t-sql because of his syntax in his question. But I was only humbly trying to share a fun idea in the middle of a stressful day trying to relax. Obviously i couldn't sum the usages in the first place so it wasn't intended to solve his problem anyway. Should i delete my post?